# Issue while saving image using savefiledialog

Tags: c#, image, bmp, savefiledialog

I'm using savefiledialog to save an image. Canvas is picturebox and the loaded image is bitmap. When I try to save it the file is created but somehow corrupted. Cause when I try againt load the image or show in different viewer it doesn't work - I mean the saved file is corrupted. There is an method for saving image.

```
 private void saveFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {

           System.IO.FileStream fs =
                (System.IO.FileStream)saveFileDialog1.OpenFile();

           try
           {
               switch (saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex)
               {
                   case 1:
                       canvas.Image.Save(saveFileDialog1.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                       break;
                   case 2:
                       canvas.Image.Save(saveFileDialog1.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                       break;
                   case 3:
                       canvas.Image.Save(saveFileDialog1.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                       break;
                   case 4:
                       canvas.Image.Save(saveFileDialog1.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff);
                       break;
               }

           }
           catch (Exception ex) 
           {
               System.Console.WriteLine("Exception " + ex);
           }
```

I should also mention the property Filter. saveFileDialog1.Filter has value:

```
bmp (*.bmp)|*.bmp|jpeg (*.jpeg)|*.jpeg|png (*.png)|*.png|tiff (*.tiff)|*.tiff
```

Comment: check to make sure the file is of the correct format after being saved to whatever folder?

Comment: And how can I check it? I save it so file is for example: image.bmp but I can't open it so the there is probably problem with saving. But I don't know where could be the problem.

Comment: I mean just right click the file and go to properties, may give more information on how its failed to save? I'm not sure though

Comment: It was first what I did, but it give me just info that the file type is bmp. But it shows me even if change some .txt file to .bmp by rewriting txt to bmp. So the properties are useless for me :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was gonna ask why you have the line

```
System.IO.FileStream fs =
    (System.IO.FileStream)saveFileDialog1.OpenFile();
```

But as it turns out, that's exactly the line causing your problems. You are opening the file to a `FileStream`. While it's open, you use `canvas.Image.Save` to write the image to that same file.

It throws an exception, but since you just write the exception to the console you don't see it.

Just remove the line I mentioned and your code will work.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to delete it. It's form example from MDSN which was based on txt file. Now it works fine. Thanks.