# How to use saveFileDialog for saving images in C#?

Tags: c#, image, savefiledialog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Issue while saving image using savefiledialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053398/issue-while-saving-image-using-savefiledialog)

I use windows forms in C#. How should I use saveFileDialog? I have picturebox and on the picture box there is an image and I want to save it. Loaded image is bmp. I want to save it as one of 4 formats: bmp, jpeg, png, tiff. I read some some notes on MDSN and also tryed it but I probably do something wrong. So I better ask how should be it write?
How should be wrote method  **private void saveFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)** and how should look like property **saveFileDialog.Filter**?
Thanks

EDIT: 
What I've tryed: 
[Issue while saving image using savefiledialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053398/issue-while-saving-image-using-savefiledialog)

EDIT2: 
I tryed this filter

```
Filter = bmp (*.bmp)|*.bmp|jpeg (*.jpeg)|*.jpeg|png (*.png)|*.png|tiff (*.tiff)|*.tiff
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053398/issue-while-saving-image-using-savefiledialog

Comment: Because you didn't describe what you've tried and what's going wrong. You're just asking us to code it for you.

Comment: @comecme If I did it nobody responded ... so I tryed it this way. I edited my post and if you click on the link you can see what I did.

Comment: @user1097772: Please don't ask the same question twice. If you don't get an answer, edit your original question.

Comment: So, because you didn't get an answer within half an hour, you reposted the question. Personally, I wouldn't do that.

Comment: @comecme No I rather changed the question.

Comment: I've answered your original question.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the SaveFileDialog like this:

```
SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
sfd.Filter = "Images|*.png;*.bmp;*.jpg";
ImageFormat format = ImageFormat.Png;
if (sfd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(sfd.FileName);
    switch (ext)
    {
        case ".jpg":
            format = ImageFormat.Jpeg;
            break;
        case ".bmp":
            format = ImageFormat.Bmp;
            break;
    }
    pictureBox1.Image.Save(sfd.FileName, format);
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, I'll try it. Can you please tell me what is wrong with this filter? 
Filter = bmp (*.bmp)|*.bmp|jpeg (*.jpeg)|*.jpeg|png (*.png)|*.png|tiff (*.tiff)|*.tiff

Comment: You are missing the *'s on the second part of the filter.

Comment: Yes but did this forum I have there * but when I pasted it the * dissapeared so I copy it to my question ;)

Comment: +1 from me just because your answer was chosen, but not upvoted...

Comment: fixed bug: `string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(sfd.FileName).ToLower();`

Comment: `sfd.Filter = "PNG Image(*.png)|*.png|JPG Image(*.jpg)|*.jpg|BMP Image(*.bmp)|*.bmp";` should give you separate options to save. Then you don't need `switch` statement.