# Download File from BLOB Oracle using c#

Tags: c#, oracle11g, devexpress, blob

i have created simple project in c# to save file data into Oracle Database using BLOB data type and it worked. i used devexpress gridcontrol to show the data. This is the sample data that i have created.

[image]

in the **btnDownload** will download data from blob oracle that i selected row. here is my code:

```
var rowHandle = gridView1.FocusedRowHandle;
var obj = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, "FILENAME");

if(koneksidb.con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{
    koneksidb.con.Close();
}
koneksidb.con.Open();
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
OracleDataReader dr;
cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM LATIHANFILEMANAGER WHERE FILENAME='"+ obj +"'";
cmd.Connection = koneksidb.con;
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while(dr.Read())
{
    UInt32 FileSize = Convert.ToUInt32(dr.GetInt32(dr.GetOrdinal("FILESIZE"))); //get file size from table LATIHANFILEMANAGER
    rawData = new byte[FileSize];
    var nilai = dr.GetBytes(dr.GetOrdinal("FILEDATA"), 0, rawData, 0, (int)FileSize); //this file that i wanna download
    FileStream fls = new FileStream(@"D:\newfile.png", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
    fls.Write(rawData, 0, (int)FileSize);
    fls.Close();
}
dr.Close();
```

when i run this project and download the image, i got a file and file size but it cannot be opened.

here is the file that i captured:

[image]

this tutorial i got from this link:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/connector-net-en/connector-net-programming-blob-reading.html

any suggest?

Answer (score 0):

first, you show your Image(BLOB) from database to PictureBox, than use SaveFileDialog.
for more information visit
[How to use saveFileDialog for saving images in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055258/how-to-use-savefiledialog-for-saving-images-in-c)

Comment: How if the file isn't image? Like .pdf, .mp4, etc for several muti format file.. it cannot be show in picturebox.. ?